# Probabilities of Electrons in Orbitals

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals, atomic-structure

I've heard both of the following:

- An orbital is a region where there's a 90% probability of finding an electron
- An orbital is a region where an electron spends 90% of its time

Are these essentially the same things? Or which one is correct and why?
Edit- I've heard both from veritable sources and only need a confirmation not a precise definition.

Comment: essentially the same thing

Comment: If an electron spends 90% of its time in an orbital, then the probability of finding an electron there is 90%; they're interchangeable in my opinion. Orbitals are where we think electrons exist anyway.

Comment: @KianStevens Like every statement in your comment is incorrect. :/

Comment: @Mithoron, can you please tell me what's correct then ?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39438/what-exactly-is-an-orbital

Comment: This is not the definition of an orbital. It is not even a volume/region dimension.